# How to escape two slashes coming from string in variable

Tags: bash, sed

I'm currently writing a script that will remove directory names from file if not found in system. However, I cannot get my sed command to work.

Current command:

```
sed -i '/"$row"/d' DirtoDelete.txt
```

`$row` expands to `//maindir/subdir/testing` <--- directory being deleted

but I keep getting the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: expected newer version of sed
```

Any ideas what's going on here? Or is there a better way to escape those leading forward slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different delimiter:

```
sed -i "\#${row}#d" DirtoDelete.txt
```

We are using `#` as the delimiter here because `$row` does not contain a `#`. (If you can't ensure that for your input data use something else). Furthermore you need to escape the starting delimiter in this case: `\#`:

From [POSIX sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

> In a context address, the construction "\cBREc", where c is any character other than backslash or newline, shall be identical to "/BRE/". If the character designated by c appears following a backslash, then it shall be considered to be that literal character, which shall not terminate the BRE. For example, in the context address "\xabc\xdefx", the second x stands for itself, so that the BRE is "abcxdef".

Comment: Don't you have to escape the first delimiter, as in `\#${row}#d`? See [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses), under `\%regexp%`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks! I never knew that.

Comment: @codeforester What was wrong with that quote? The source does say" <newline>" and "<backspace>", with the angle brackets.

Comment: For some reason, my browser (Chrome on macOS) wouldn't show those words.

Comment: @codeforester Oh, I get it now - they were interpreted as HTML tags and disappeared. Should have been `&lt;newline&gt;` (see [this meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203709/how-can-i-format-to-show-text-inside-and)).

Answer (score 2):

I know there's a duplicate of this question. Nevertheless:

If you change delimiters, you'll have to escape *those* in the string, so just bite the bullet and escape the slashes:

```
$ row=//maindir/subdir/testing
$ echo "${row//\//\\/}"
\/\/maindir\/subdir\/testing
$ echo $'first\nline with '"$row"$'\nlast'
first
line with //maindir/subdir/testing
last
$ echo $'first\nline with '"$row"$'\nlast' | sed "/${row//\//\\/}/d"
first
last
```

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the bash manual.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to abuse regular expressions for literate text substitution. awk `index` function finds substrings.

```
$ cat r
d="$1"; shift
awk -v d="$d" '{
    s = $0
    while (i = index(s, d))
        s = substr(s, 1, i - 1) substr(s, i + length(d))
    print s
}' "$@"
```

Usage:

```
$ echo '/a/b = /a/b' | sh r 'a/b'
/ = /
```